# Fetch mysql data using while condition in div

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

Before i was displaying zones records static although i have records in database table

**HTML**

```
<div class="pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_fst">
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=1">Kosi</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=2">Mechi</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=3">Sagarmatha</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_sec">
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=6">Bagmati</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=7">Janakpur</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=8">Narayani</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_thrd">
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=9">Dhawalagiri</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=10">Gandaki</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=11">Lumbini</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_frth">
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=12">Bheri</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=13">Karnali</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val=14">Rapti</a></h2>
</div>
```

Now i want to fetch zone records using while or whatever method that work for me!

```
<?php
$sql="select * from tb_zone";
$res =mysql_query($sql);
while($data =mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        // want do display zone record in the above html output format
    }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: where in the html output ? you want replace val ? or the names ?what result you want

Comment: @echo_Samir i want to load `val` value and `<a>` tag value (kosi, mechi etc) from mysql table using while loop or any method but each 3 zone list should be grouped in div tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
 <?php
$class = array ('pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_fst','pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_sec','pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_thrd','pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_frth'); 
$sql="select * from tb_zone";
$res =mysql_query($sql);
$j=0;
$i=0;
while($data =mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
       if($i==0)
       {   echo '<div class="'.$class[$j].'">';   }

         echo  '<h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val='.$data["value"].'">'.$data["zone"].'</a></h2>';

         if($i%2==0 && i > 0)
       {   echo '</div>';  $j++;$i=0; }
       else{    $i++;    }




    }



 ?>
```

Comment: i want to load `val` value and `<a>` tag value (kosi, mechi etc) from mysql table using while loop or any method but each 3 zone list should be grouped in div tag.. will this script work?

Answer (score 0):

just use this type

```
while($data =mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

echo
'
<div class="pub_fot_sec_menu pub_fot_list_fst">
    <h2><a href="index.php?pages=zilla.php&val='.$data['value'].'">'.$data['zone'].'</a></h2>
';
}
```

Comment: in this script i am assuming that you have stored page value also in the table with zone

Comment: i want to load `val` value and `<a>` tag value (kosi, mechi etc) from mysql table using while loop or any method but each 3 zone list should be grouped in div tag